# Need redirect to login for Ms.AspNetCore.Identity 2.0 if not authorized

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I need to redirect to login page if user is logged but doesn't have corresponding role. This is easily achieved in .net core 1.1.2 via [AuthorizeAttribute]

```
 [Authorize(Roles="Manager")]
```

If I bootstrap .Net Core 2.0 web app with asp.net core Identity 2.0.1, this  redirect to /Account/AccessDenied, instead of Login.

This is from Startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
            options => {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            }
            )
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
```

Answer (score 2):

resolved by this code:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {              
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";              
        });
```